# System.Linq.Expression Query Convert

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

```cs
public DataSourceResult GetCustomerList (DataSourceRequest request)
{
   Result <==  List<Customer> Collection Object

   Result.Where( **p=> !p.State && ( (p=>p.Day>10 && p.Day<20) || (p.Name.Length<40 && p.EndsWith(“s”)  )** )

   //instead of the above query expression

   p=> !p.State && ( (p=>p.Day>10 && p.Day<20) || (p.Name.Length<40 && p.EndsWith(“s”)  ) <= Convert  CompositeFilterDescriptor 

   request.filtes.Add( CompositeFilterDescriptor)

   return Result.ToDataSourceResult(request);
}
```

As per example I want to convert the query filter where the `datasourcerequest`

Answer (score 0):

we don't want with where all collection, we want create same where function with CompositeFilterDescriptor

I want to create CompositeFilterDescriptor but
filter should be the same as 
p=> !p.State && ( (p=>p.Day>10 && p.Day<20) || (p.Name.Length<40 && p.EndsWith(“s”)  ) 
if ;
Result.Where( p=> !p.State && ( (p=>p.Day>10 && p.Day<20) || (p.Name.Length<40 && p.EndsWith(“s”)  ) ) Output=> 10
it must be;
Result.ToDataSourceResult(request); Output=>10

results should be the same